# Find and replace text in /etc/mail/sendmail.cf using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I want to replace

> #Dj$w.Foo.COM

with

> Dj server.local.com

in /etc/mail/sendmail.cf

I am using

```
sed -i "/#Dj$w.Foo.COM/c\Dj server.local.com" /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

but the effect is not taking place

Comment: Try `sed -i 's/#Dj\$w\.Foo\.COM/Dj server.local.com/' /etc/mail/sendmail.cf`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor,
But getting an error
sed: -e expression #1,  char 37: unterminated `s' command

Comment: It looks [working fine](https://ideone.com/S7EVOW). You are not using my command then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```bash
sed -i 's/#Dj\$w\.Foo\.COM/Dj server.local.com/' /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/S7EVOW):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='#Dj$w.Foo.COM'
sed 's/#Dj\$w\.Foo\.COM/Dj server.local.com/' <<< "$s"
# => Dj server.local.com
```